# Ordenar array de objetos

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional, order

Tenho como resultado de uma consulta ao banco de dados os seguintes dados:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome] => Pizzaria 1
            [latitude] => -8.12044775643893
            [longitude] => -35.025825550000036
            [distancia] => 3800
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [nome] => Pizzaria 2
            [latitude] => -7.90856162499827
            [longitude] => -34.91269575000001
            [distancia] => 1500
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [nome] => Pizzaria 3
            [latitude] => -8.12044775643893
            [longitude] => -35.025825550000036
            [distancia] => 2000
        )
)
```

Só que estou adicionando a entrada **distancia** depois, pois ela não existe no banco. Ela serve para guardar o valor de um cálculo de distância, em metros, feito quando o usuário entra na pagina para que seja ordenado do mais próximo para o mais distante.

Minha dúvida é como eu faço para ordenar esse array de objetos para que a distância fique em ordem crescente?

Answer (score 7):

Para esses e outros casos, [usort()](http://www.php.net/usort) é quem você procura.

Porém, ligeiramente diferente dos exemplos do manual, você deve informar as propriedades que serão usadas como base para comparação.

Não é lá muito diferente do primeiro exemplo, veja:

```
usort(

    $data,

     function( $a, $b ) {

         if( $a -> distancia == $b -> distancia ) return 0;

         return ( ( $a  -> distancia < $b  -> distancia ) ? -1 : 1 );
     }
);
```

A saída, como esperado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [nome] => Pizzaria 2
            [latitude] => -7.9085616249983
            [longitude] => -34.91269575
            [distancia] => 1500
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [nome] => Pizzaria 3
            [latitude] => -8.1204477564389
            [longitude] => -35.02582555
            [distancia] => 2000
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome] => Pizzaria 1
            [latitude] => -8.1204477564389
            [longitude] => -35.02582555
            [distancia] => 3800
        )

)
```

Comment: Antiga, mas muito útil.